# Confusion with Tablet Support in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to optimize my Android application for Tablets in the Google Play Store

As per the documentation here -

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions

It is asking me to give the minSdkVersion as 11 or higher

Now my problem is if I give this, my application will stop showing to users below API level 11, like Gingerbred(API level 10), which is still a very high % age

Anyone having ideas on how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to use the support library so that it is compatible with versions lower than SDK 11 and still work on anything above

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question correctly. 

If I give the minSdkversion as 11 in the manifest file, the application will not show up to the user with API level less than 11 in Google Play Store, hence they won't be able to download

This way, my application will miss all the Gingerbred handsets out there

Comment: with the support library you can make the minimum sdk 2.2 since that is what the support library goes to